# Search in a DataGrid by entering a word in the textBox

Tags: c#, wpf, csv

I created a Datagrid In WPF, C# with 8 columns and 190 rows that loads data from a csv file. Now I have created a TextBox where I write a word and it must search for it in the DataGrid and display all the words found in the same Datagrid1. The code I created gives me an error in MainWindow.xaml.

This is the error:

> CS1061 'type' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no
> accessible extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type
> 'type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
> assembly reference?).

Notice: error message is from [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061), and may not reflect the correct message eg. 'type' could be the actual type instead of this wild card

This is the MainWindow.xaml code:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox_Cerca" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="84,49,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="128" 
    RenderTransformOrigin="-0.775,-0.722" 
    Height="22" 
    TextChanged="TexttBox_Cerca_TextChanged" 
    KeyUp="FilterTextBox_CercaChanged" />
```

Code c#:

```cs
private void TexttBox_Cerca_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var filterTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    var filterText = filterTextBox.Text;

    SetRowVisibilityByFilterText(filterText);
}

private void SetRowVisibilityByFilterText(string filterText)
{
    GetVisibleRows(DataGrid1)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(
            x =>
            {
                if (x == null) return;
                x.Visibility =
                    DataMatchesFilterText(x.Item as OttoColonne, filterText) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    });
}

private bool DataMatchesFilterText(OttoColonne? ottoColonne, string filterText)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}    

public static IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetVisibleRows(DataGrid grid)
{
    if (grid == null || grid.Items == null) yield break;
    int count = grid.ItemsSource == null
        ? grid.Items.Count
        : grid.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count();


    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        yield return (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
    }
}

class OttoColonne
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Squadra_casa { get; set; }
    public string Squadra_fuoric { get; set; }
    public string Ris_cas { get; set; }
    public string Ris_fuorc { get; set; }
    public string segni { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Giornate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your erorr is a compile time error, but the code provided doesn't have this error. Did you check error list (View --> Error List)? which file/line does the error appear? eg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7fAI.png

Comment: The error gives me in the file: MainWindow.xaml at line 26, which would be this: KeyUp="FilterTextBox_CercaChanged" />

Comment: does your code behind define `FilterTextBox_CercaChanged` it is missing in the provided code

Comment: Note you can double click on the error and it should navigate you to the file/line that has an error, once you are there the error should be highlighted and colored red - as the error message should contain the type and name that is causing problems

Comment: Double clicking on the error always takes me to line 26.
I corrected the error you reported. I deleted line 25 in the MainWindow.xaml file and changed line 26 like this: KeyUp="TextBox_CercaChanged" /> Now it gives me another error that I don't understand: Compiler error CS0123. Double clicking on the error always takes me there.

Comment: The event you are registering to doesn’t match the signature of the method you have provided. eg. the method needs to have `KeyEventArgs` if used for the `KeyUp` event

Comment: Same like your current provided code uses `TextChangedEventArgs` for the `TextChanged` event

Comment: Fixed compilation issue. But as soon as I type a letter in the textbox this line gets an error: : grid.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count();

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you always filter data collections by filtering the collection view. This produces simple and performant code. For example, focusing on the data eliminates the need to deal with container virtualization.

The following example hides the rows that doesn't match the filter predicate by assigning a filter delegate to the `ICollectionView.Filter` property.
The default collection view of a collection is obtained by using the static helper method `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`:

**User.cs**

```cs
// Example data item to populate a two column DataGrid
class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private ObservableCollection<DataGridItem> Users { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
 
    this.Users = new ObservableCollection<DataGridItem>() 
    { 
      // TODO::Initialize collection with User items 
    };
    this.UsersDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.Users;
  }

  private void OnFilterButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    string usernamePredicate = this.FilterPredicateTextBox.Text;
    ICollectionView usersView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Users);

    // Only display the users 
    // where the Username value matches the usernamePredicate value
    usersView.Filter = item => (item as User).Username.Equals(usernamePredicate, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="FilterPredicateTextBox" />
    <Button Content="Execute DataGrid Filter" 
            Click="OnFilterButtonClicked" />
    <DataGrid x:Name="UsersDataGrid" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: It gives me an error on this line:
string usernamePredicate = this.FilterPredicateTextBox.Text;
My intelligence tells me to remove 'this', I removed it but it always gives me error CS0029

Comment: The above example works. Your error is related to a missing cast. Are you running the exact same code from above?

Answer (score 0):

The bionic code code doesn't work. I'm using the library
CsvHelper to display .csv file data in a datagrid. So far so good. Now inserting some text in a textbox I have to look for it in the datagrid. This is the new code:

```
private void SearchTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            string searchText = SearchTextBox.Text;
            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = new CsvReader().GetItems().Where(x => x[1].Contains(searchText)).ToList();
            DataGrid1.SelectedItem = DataGrid1.ItemsSource.FirstOrDefault();
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
```

It gives me 2 errors. One under this entry: CsvReader(), and another: FirstOrDefault().
The first: 'CsvReader' doesn't contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
The second one:
'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition of 'FirstOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'FirstOrDefault' was found that takes a first argument of type 'IEnumerable'. Probably missing a using directive or assembly reference.

How do I fix these 2 errors? Intelligence gives me no correction.